# django-admin startproject myproject is not working

Tags: django, bash, macos, python-3.6

I'm new to django and wanted to begin learning it but I am stuck at creating a new project. So, far I tried command `django-admin startproject mysite` and `django-admin.py startproject mysite` but the outcome produces `-bash: django-admin.py: command not found` and `-bash: django-admin: command not found`.

I also tried this in a virtualenv but it produces the same thing.

`(mysite) xxxxxxx (master *+) django-tutorial $ django-admin startproject myproject
-bash: django-admin: command not found
(mysite) xxxxxx (master *+) django-tutorial $ django-admin.py startproject myproject
-bash: django-admin.py: command not found`

I am running mac osx el capitan

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have python installed in your computer and which python version you are using. And also make sure you also have django installed, running this command in your terminal: python -m django --version. Check here for more detail: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/intro/tutorial01/

Comment: I installed django but it wasn't installed in virtualenv. Thanks dude!